Numerical Angular Geodesic Equation
I'm currently trying to solve the following equation numerically:
$$\dfrac{d\phi}{dy} = \pm \dfrac{b}{y^2}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 - b^2\dfrac{A(y)}{y^2}}} $$
In which $A(y) = 1 - \dfrac{2}{y}$.
Here's the problem, you want to start out integrating the minus sign solution, since initially, as the angle increases the radius decreases, until it reaches a minimum, i.e, $\dfrac{d\phi}{dy} = 0$, that's when you want to start integrating the plus sign solution. However, I'm in trouble when I try to change between one integration to another, my plus sign numerical integration(called sol2b) doesn't have as many entries as it should, because of the switching point between one to the other being identified too late. Can anyone help me?
Here's some of my code.
φi = 0
yi = 100 
yf = 10**(-12)
Nsteps = 40     # Amount of geodesic we are dealing with

bc = np.sqrt(27)* (1 + 10**(-5))
bin = bc* (1 + 3)
bfin = bc* (1 - 19/100)

b_values = np.linspace(bin, bfin, Nsteps)
y = np.linspace(yi,yf, 10000)

# define the ingoing angular geodesic equation 

def dφdyminus(φ,y,b): 
    argument = 1 - (b**2 * (1 - 2/y))/y**2
    if argument <= 0 or y < 1e-10:
        return 0
    return -(b/y**2) * 1/np.sqrt(argument)

#define the outgoing angular geodesic equation
def dφdyplus(φ,y,b): 
    argument = 1 - (b**2 * (1 - 2/y))/y**2
    if argument <= 0 or y < 1e-10:
        return 0
    return (b/y**2) * 1/np.sqrt(argument)

plt.figure()
for b in b_values:
    # Solve the ingoing geodesic
    sol2a = odeint(dφdyminus, φi, y, args=(b,))
   
   # Find the switching point
    max_sol2a = np.nanmax(sol2a)  # Calculate max once
    switch_index = None
    for i in range(len(sol2a)):
        if np.isnan(sol2a[i]) or sol2a[i] == max_sol2a or sol2a[i] == sol2a[i-1]:
            switch_index = i-1
            break

    # Use the last valid point as the initial condition for the outgoing geodesic
    φinew = sol2a[switch_index] if switch_index > 0 else φi
    ynew = y[switch_index:]
   
    # Solve the outgoing geodesic
    sol2b = odeint(dφdyplus, φinew, ynew, args=(b,))
   
    # Combine solutions
    combined_newy = np.append(y[:switch_index], ynew)
    combined_sol2 = np.append(sol2a[:switch_index], sol2b)

    # make it polar 
    x_coords = combined_newy * np.cos(combined_sol2) # this projects the generated data from the simulation into the polar plane
    y_coords = combined_newy * np.sin(combined_sol2)
    plt.plot(x_coords, y_coords, color = 'gray')

plt.axhline(0, color='black', lw=0.5)
plt.axvline(0, color='black', lw=0.5)
plt.xlim(-30,30)
plt.ylim(-20,20)
plt.show() ```


can't you boil this down to a minimal reproducible example, maybe just the root?

Actually no, it would not make much sense since this equation is derive from the geometry space that we are dealing with.
